# rails syntax error.. unexpected end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError in FriendsController#index

/Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal/app/controllers/friends_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
/Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal/app/controllers/friends_controller.rb:58: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
Rails.root: /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
client_side_validations (3.1.4) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4243183701801146600__call__3008343249707344054__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My view:

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @friends = Friend.all
end

  def show
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @friend }
    end
  end

  def new
    @friend = Friend.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @friend }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(params[:friend]
  end

  def update
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.update_attributes(params[:friend])
        format.html { redirect_to @friend, notice: 'Friend was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end



  def destroy
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
    @friend.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to friends_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's not the view, that's the controller...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an end at the end of your update:

```
@friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @friend.update_attributes(params[:friend])
      format.html { redirect_to @friend, notice: 'Friend was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end #add this one :)
```

And your create is missing a closing bracket at the end of it:

```
def create
  @friend = Friend.new(params[:friend])
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `update` method is missing its `end`.

Answer (score 3):

Your update method is missing an end